# Action declaration doesn't work properly

Tags: redux, flowtype

I activated flow in my project with redux, but the Action declarations doesn't work as I expected.
Declarations are:

```
type PostRequest = {
  type: string;
};

type PostPayload = {
  posts: Object;
  offset: number;
  hasMore: boolean;
};

type PostSuccess = {
  type: string;
  payload: PostPayload;
};

type PostError = {
  type: string;
};

type PostSelected = {
  type: string;
  postId: string;
};

export type Action = PostSuccess | PostError | PostSelected | PostRequest;
```

In actionCreators I don't see any errors, while reducer I get this error in the use of property "payload": `property 'payload' (Property not found in object type)`.
This is my reducer:

```
import type { Action } from "../types";
// other import...

export default function(state: State = initialState, action: Action):
State {
  switch (action.type) {
    // ...
    case POST_SUCCESS: {
      const { posts, offset, hasMore } = action.payload;
      return {
        ...state,
        isFetching: false,
        posts: _.merge(state.posts, posts),
        offset: state.offset + offset,
        hasMore,
      };
    }
    // ...
```

What is the correct way to declare Actions?

Answer (score 2):

You can define [Disjoint Unions](https://flowtype.org/blog/2015/07/03/Disjoint-Unions.html)

```
type ActionA = {
  type: 'A',
  a: number
};

type ActionB = {
  type: 'B',
  b: string
};

type Action = ActionA | ActionB;

type State = number;

function reducer(state: State, action: Action): State {
  switch(action.type) {
    case 'A' :
      return action.a
    case 'B' :
      return action.b.length
    default :
      (action: null) // check for exhaustivity
      throw `unknown action`
  }
}
```

Comment: Disjoint unions is what I already do, however, applying the type to "string" to make it more generic.
The way you've shown is not an acceptable solution as it doesn't allow me to use the action types as constants.

Comment: Using the type `string` doesn't make them more generic, they are just no more disjoint unions (e.g `PostRequest` and `PostError`). If you don't use string literal types (see the linked documentation), Flow will not be able to refine the action.

Comment: This is the right answer. There is no way for any analysis to statically prove that the code in the original question is correct. For example, I could dispatch an action `{type: POST_SUCCESS}` (which matches the type `PostError` as written). Attempting to destructure `action.payload` in the switch statement would be a runtime error.